# how to make use of STL's for better result and performance in this issue

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have some set of strings in format : `country/currency/minimum_amount`

For example:

```
US/USD/18
US/EUR/20
DE/USD/22
GB/EUR/19
```

Let's say i have drop downs each for country, currency and minimum amount.
Once i select the country, i should get the possible combination of currency and min amount from the above set of strings.

ex. Once i select country as US in dropdown_1, then currency(dropdown) should display - USD and EUR and min_amt - 18 and 20.\
ex. 2:
Once i select Currency as USD in dropdown_2, then country(dropdown) should display - US and DE and min_amt - 18 and 22.. similarly for the third drop down as well.

My solution, 
Lets assume i have these specific strings in a vector(name - myvector),
then I'm retrieving the strings using:

```
std::string str2("US"); // i need the strings that has country as US
string credt_fin_str;

for (unsigned j=0; j<myvector.size(); j++)
{
    credt_fin_str = myvector.at(j);
    std::size_t found = credt_fin_str.find(str2);

    if(found != string::npos)
    {
        std::cout<<"creditfin found:"<<credt_fin_str<<std::endl;
    }

}
```

Output:

```
US/USD/18
US/EUR/20
DE/USD/22
```

Since i using string::find, it displays even "USD" as it contains "US" but it shouldn't be for my use case.

can anyone suggest a better solution to this use case so that i can improve the result and performance.

Comment: Side note: you do not need vector.at(index) while iterating over valid indices, use vector[]

Comment: why don't you split your string by '/' character and store each combination in a vector?

Comment: @sithereal, if i do so, how can i relate country/currency/amount?? since there are more valid combinations as well..

Comment: @LogeshwariRam Don't make the mistake of trying to write your code depending on the UI. Look up what the "MVC pattern" is all about. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Comment: @LogeshwariRam - From your description, it looks like a std::map representing your data is a much better choice than a set of vectors.

Comment: @LogeshwariRam: They'll be in the same vector and if you can be sure that the positions of country/currency/amount won't change; then you can access them via their constant indice(eg: if(vec1[0] == "US))

Comment: Store it in any container you like. Considering the low number of countries and currencies worldwide, it is probably fast enough. If that turns out as too slow, there is something in the data you have forgotten to tell us here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use [`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/).

Map each country name to vector of possible combinations. Typical workflow for this goes as follow:

1. Parse input string
2. Store parsing results
3. Query storage container

So, start with structure for results:

```
struct CurrencyVal
{
    string currency;
    int minimum_ammount;
};
```

It will be stored in the vector for each country. This represents single entry like `USD/18` and is not related to any country.

Now, lets make some space for storing it:

```
std::map<string,vector<CurrencyVal>> dropdowns;
```

It will map any country to list of possible CurrencyVal values. Lets now parse the input vector. Lets say the input vector is `vector<string> input`.

```
//Helper function, note the pos is passed by reference to modify it
string parseToToken(string& str, int& pos, char delim)
{
    string result="";
    for (; pos<str.length(); pos++)
    {
        if (str[pos] == delim)
            break;
        result+=str[pos];
    }
    pos++; //Skip the token
    return result;
}

for (unsigned i=0; i<input.size(); i++)
{
    int pos = 0;
    string country;
    CurrencyVal value;

    country = parseToToken(input[i],pos,'/');
    value.currency = parseToToken(input[i],pos,'/');

    //stoi from <string> in C++11, if you are not using c++11, try with atoi(input[i].substr(pos).c_str())
    value.minimum_ammount = stoi(input[i].substr(pos)); 

    //Store the results
    dropdowns[country].push_back(value);
}
```

That's all. Now we can query this struct like this:

```
vector<CurrencyVal> allForUs = dropdowns["US"];
for (unsigned i = 0; i < allForUs.size(); i++)
    cout << allForUs[i].country << " - " << allForUs[i].minimum_ammound << endl;
```

If you have any questions post a comment so I can improve this answer.

Comment: In the code to display the entries in the vector, use `map::find` instead of `[ ]`.  If the value doesn't exist, you won't be creating empty entries if `find` is used.

Comment: @kittyPL : This is fine for searching by country. The problem here is i i can search for country/currency/min_amount, so that other i get the combination of the other two.

Comment: @LogeshwariRam You can use multipe dictionaries. Yes, that's how it works in most professional apps.

Comment: @kittyPL could you please elaborate more on this?

Comment: Create struct for each pair like I did for CurrencyVal along with appropiate map (dictionary). Then after parsing each input line add all three structs to their maps :)